# Replacing a div content with other text content using javascript

Tags: html

how to change one div content to other content (content is just some text) by a click of button.... 
The problem really is an existing div content is a video but when i click on a button it should be replaced with some text!!! –

I've tried a few things but I've been unsuccessful.... Plz help; and I've a very less knowledge about javascript......

```html
<label style="position:absolute;top:130px;left:50px;"> <input type="image" src="about.jpg" height=80 width=320 onclick="about()">
</label>
```

Comment: If you have tried something then you should include that attempt in your question

Comment: Hi! Welcome to stackOverflow. In order to get help faster you need to provide more information about your problem. What have you tried so far? And what are the problems you are facing?

Comment: I'm new here so i'm not really able to post an image;

Comment: The problem really is an existing div content is a video but when i click on a button it should be replaced with some text!!!